# Area of the square

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Can you find the area of the following square given the known lengths?

Good luck!

[image: puzzle square]

Comment: just checking: did you make this yourself?

Comment: No. I've been sent this problem by a friend, but I do not have the original source.

Comment: This is a classic puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagonal of the square is

> $\sqrt{(9+3)^2+5^2} = \sqrt{169} = 13$

so the area of the square is

> $(\frac{13}{\sqrt{2}})^2 = \frac{169}{2}$

Comment: OMG that is so brilliant! No mucking around with trigonometry and simultaneous equations with multiple unknowns. THANK YOU!

Comment: My pleasure. :)